# removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers: didn't work on latest iOS 12 beta version

Tags: push-notification, nsnotificationcenter, ios12

I used group push notification in my application.

I added a custom key/value pair identified notification type in the payload, and I would delete the push notification in the notification center if got a same type by using the API `removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers` from `UNUserNotificationCenter`.

It works fine on iOS 11 which built from Xcode 9.4.1
When I ran the app on iOS 12 (latest beta version), the remove API didn't work.

Any solution? I have no idea is it a system bug.

---

**Update:**

I upgraded my Xcode to 10.0 GM version, and upgraded iOS 12 to release version on my iPhone.
This method still didn't work in most time. But in sometimes, it can remove the notifications.